# Counter to add seperator on foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have an foreach to add terms to a post on Wordpress Which is working great. Code below:

```
<h3>
<?php foreach($terms as $term) {?>
    <?php echo $term->name;?>
<?php } ?>
</h3>
```

However I need to add a counter so that if there is more than one term in the `<h3>` it adds a / between them. For instance:

```
<h3>Term Name</h3>
<h3>Term Name / Term Name / Term Name</h3>
```

This is the code I have so far however its not working.

```
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach($terms as $term) {

        if($i == 1){ 
         echo ' / '.$term->name;
        } else { 
            echo $term->name;
        }   
        $i++;  
        } ?>
```

Comment: Your $i is one for the first loop but you need / after first pass , try $i == 2

Comment: You dont need a `<?php` on every line, just one at the start of a block of PHP code and a `?>` at the end

Comment: You have a problem in your code. First of all question mark (?) is appearing inside your if and else statement and you did one logical mistake. If $i is equals to 1 then you no need /, you need / on else statement. Good Luck with your own code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a counter. Just put each `$term->name` in to an array, and implode it:

`echo implode(' / ', array_map(function($term) { return $term->name; }, $terms));`

#### [Here's a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hkWHC7)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
<?php $terms = array_values($terms); 
if( sizeof($terms) > 1){ ?>
        <h3><?php echo  implode(' / ', array_map(function($term) { return $term->name; }, $terms)); ?></h3>
<?php }else{ $term = $terms[0]; ?>
            <h3>echo $term->name;</h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: How are you going to remove the trailing slash?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($terms as $term) {  
        if($i > 1) { 
            echo ' / '.$term->name;
        } else { 
            echo $term->name;
            $i++; 
        } 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution :)

```
 <?php 
    $terms = array("Term One","Term Two","Term Three","Term Four");
    $i = 1;
    $result="";
    foreach($terms as $term)
    {
        if($i==1)
         {
            $result=$result.$term.' ';
            $i++;   
          } 
        else
            {               
                $result=$result."/".' ';
                $result=$result.$term.' ';
            }       

    }
   echo $result;    
 ?>
```

Comment: Thsi is the simple one without using any built in functions :)